# Laravel Class 'GeneaLabs\LaravelCasts\FormFacade' not found (0)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I'm a bit stuck here I cannot get the FormFacade to work everytime I load my view it throws the error.

```
ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Class 'GeneaLabs\LaravelCasts\FormFacade' not found (View: 
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Laravel\howlong\resources\views\index.blade.php)
Previous exceptions
Class 'GeneaLabs\LaravelCasts\FormFacade' not found (0)
```

I've added

```
'providers' => [
    Collective\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,
],
```

and also

```
'aliases' => [
    'Form' => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Html' => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
],
```

In my composer.json I have

```
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.7"
```

and I have run

```
composer update
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Still no luck, what am I doing wrong?

This is Laravel 5.7.14

My full composer.json

```
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "type": "project",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": [
            "framework",
            "laravel"
        ],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
            "php": "^7.1.3",
            "askedio/laravel5-profanity-filter": "^1.10",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
            "genealabs/laravel-casts": "^0.8.2",
            "laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
            "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
            "laravelcollective/html": "^5.7"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0",
            "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
        },
        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": []
            }
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "app/"
            },
            "classmap": [
                "database/seeds",
                "database/factories"
            ]
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true,
        "scripts": {
            "post-autoload-dump": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
            ],
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you add the view too? Also try composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

The path **GeneaLabs\LaravelCasts\FormFacade** is wrong, it should have been **GeneaLabs\LaravelCasts\Facades\FormFacade**, and belongs to g**enealabs/laravel-casts** package. Are you using this package anywhere?

Please correct it to the bellow,

> GeneaLabs\LaravelCasts\Facades\FormFacade

Comment: Where would I change that?

Comment: Just searched the entire of Laravel for GeneaLabs\LaravelCasts\FormFacade and it doesnt' exist, so confused where this is coming from?

Comment: Fixed it I changed it iin \bootstrap\cache\packages.php 
This must be this bug in the package? Suprised more haven't come across this issue?? https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-casts/issues/86